# Can only edit one Instant Article at a time

Tags: facebook-instant-articles

- I go to "Publishing Tools" > "Instant Articles"
- I am able to select the "Production" or "Development" directories.
- I click "+create" and am presented with a blank document that instructs me to 'paste in some HTML.'
- I paste in the HTML for my Instant Article and click "Save"
- I am able to view the Instant Article via the Page Manager App
- I want to create a second IA in the same directory (Production or Development)
- I go back to "Publishing Tools" > "Instant Articles"
- I select which ever directory I created the first IA in
- I click "+create" (for the second time now) and am again prompted to paste in HTML
- I paste in the HTML for my second IA and click save
- Now the second article is viewable via the Page Manager app and the first one has been deleted / overwritten / is gone

Is anyone else experiencing this problem?

Comment: Check your syntax regarding https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/reference. The article must be strict to this reference otherwise your last article will be update and replace the previous article added. If your article still has an error you can edit it one at a time no matter how many article you added.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the error. It seems that facebook's chache is messed up. So just add new articles to your page, pull the the stuff inside the

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[ ]]></content:encoded>
```

from your rss feed and paste it into the code editor in facebook.

You should be able to create more articles this way.